# Powershell - change file Date Created and Date Modified based on Filename

Tags: powershell

I have lots of file scanned PDF documents that have the file named with an included date. For example:

```
FileA_2017-10-15.pdf
FileB_2016-04-08.pdf
FileC_2018-01-30.pdf
```

some files also are formatted with an underscore at the end as well such as...

```
FileD_2018-01-30_1.pdf
FileE_2018-01-30_2.pdf
```

there are even a few that have two underscores before the date such as...

```
FileF_Example_2018-01-30_1.pdf
FileG_Example_2018-01-30_2.pdf
```

Unfortunately, the date they were scanned in is different than the actual date of the document. So the "Date Created" and "Date Modified" attributes are different than what is shown in the file name.

I would like a script that I could run to change the "Date Created" and "Date Modified" to match that of the filename.

I attempted this using someone else's script but I don't know enough about PowerShell to make it actually work. Note that I do not want to change the name of the file, only the time stamp.

```
$Directory = "C:\TestFolder"
$DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"


foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem $Directory)) {
    $date_from_file=GetFileName::[datetime])

    $file.CreationTime = $date_from_file
    $file.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file
    $file.LastWriteTime = $date_from_file

    Write-Host ($file.Name + " - " + $date_from_file)
    }
```

The code above can be scraped if something else has already been written since what I have doesn't work.

***Edit***
Wondering if it would also be possible to add to the script so that it could include files in sub-folders as well. Maybe it could be scripted in a way that would only consider the files in a folder if the Date Modified on the folder is today. I would like to run this on a parent folder that could potentially have many sub-folders and if those folders don't have a "Date Modified" of today, then it should skip the files in that folder. I was thinking that could speed up the process. Open to thoughts and thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You are quite near, you need

- split the date part from filename and convert it to a [datetime]
- I use a RegEx with a capture group anchored at the end `$` of the BaseName

```
## Q:\Test\2019\05\19\SO_56211626.ps1
$Directory = "C:\TestFolder"

foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path $Directory -Filter *.pdf)){
    if($File.BaseName -match '_(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})(_\d)?$'){
        $date_from_file= (Get-Date $Matches[1])

        $file.CreationTime   = $date_from_file
        $file.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file
        $file.LastWriteTime  = $date_from_file
        $file | Select-Object Name,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
> Q:\Test\2019\05\19\SO_56211626.ps1

Name                 CreationTime        LastAccessTime      LastWriteTime
----                 ------------        --------------      -------------
FileA_2017-10-15.pdf 2017-10-15 00:00:00 2017-10-15 00:00:00 2017-10-15 00:00:00
FileB_2016-04-08.pdf 2016-04-08 00:00:00 2016-04-08 00:00:00 2016-04-08 00:00:00
FileC_2018-01-30.pdf 2018-01-30 00:00:00 2018-01-30 00:00:00 2018-01-30 00:00:00
```

An English locale (en-US) produces:

```
Name                 CreationTime           LastAccessTime         LastWriteTime
----                 ------------           --------------         -------------
FileA_2017-10-15.pdf 10/15/2017 12:00:00 AM 10/15/2017 12:00:00 AM 10/15/2017 12:00:00 AM
FileB_2016-04-08.pdf 4/8/2016 12:00:00 AM   4/8/2016 12:00:00 AM   4/8/2016 12:00:00 AM
FileC_2018-01-30.pdf 1/30/2018 12:00:00 AM  1/30/2018 12:00:00 AM  1/30/2018 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: Hmm. I ran your script using Powershell ISE, but nothing happened. The file dates didn't change and there was no output either. Maybe I missed something?

Comment: Ok, so it ONLY works if the name of the file is "FileA_yyyy-mm-dd". That was only an example though, so how can we make it match ANY file name followed by an underscore with date?

Comment: But that **IS** exactly what the RegEx does, if it was copied as is, it works here also in ISE.`

Comment: I'm not certain I completely understand. So maybe PowerShell is not the best tool for this. Sorry for my ignorance. Also, I just discovered that sometimes my files may have an underscore at the end as well. For example it could be ExampleFile_10-15-2017_2.

Comment: If you change your requirements without telling us, the solutions won't fit. My RegEx expects exactly the formatting of your example, underscore 4digits dash 2digits dash 2digits at the end of the BaseName. If the RegEx doesn't match the file is ignored. Lee_Dailey's ParseExact errors out because the pattern doesn't match. So I suggest to supply more real world examples in a new question - this one was answered correctly to your initial req's. Wasting people's time won't make you friends.

Comment: Hi LotPings. You stated that your regex should match the basename_xxxx-xx-xx.pdf. The only change I made was renaming the basename from "FileA" to "Example" to see if it would still modify the date. It did not, and I reported back with those results. My interpretation from your response is that the basename of the file must be "FileA". Is that what you meant or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Your script is working. My apologies. I had a space between my basename and the underscore that was causing the problem. Any way to tweak the regex to match BETWEEN two underscores or with only one underscore at the beginning? I'm guessing probably not. Thanks again!

Comment: I changed the RegEx to have an (optional) trailing underscore with a digit.

Comment: That works well. Thank you. I also added the recurse command to perform this in subfolders as well. I'll use this for a while and post back if I need further changes. To avoid unnecessarily changing the time stamps on files that are already correct, I would like to consider adding a part to the script to only make this change if the file "date created" is today? I can create a new post for that. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

*[
edit - since the OP is getting very strange errors with my suggested fix - errors that i cannot reproduce with the sample data - i've changed this answer to the full suggested code.
edit 2 - added new file name variants and code to deal with them.

edit 3 - changed from splitting to a regex match since the sample data has changed yet again. [*sigh ...*] 
]*

<s>you are not actually creating the datetime object that you need. the `$date_from_file=` line doesn't actually do anything other than create red error msgs ... [*grin*]</s>

replace this line ...

```
$date_from_file=GetFileName::[datetime])
```

... with this line ...

```
$date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($File.BaseName.Split('_')[-1], $DateFormat, $Null)
```

... and your `$date_from_file` variable will contain a proper `[datetime]` object that will work in your assignments.

i would likely change the sequence of those assignments to put the `$file.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file` LAST so that it doesn't get changed by the next line.

also, that value will change any time that the file is accessed, so it may not be worth changing. [*grin*]

---

here is the full script along with what it does -

what it does ...

- sets the location & the date format to use
- creates a set of test files from the OPs sample file names
- gets the files from the source
- converts the `.BaseName` into a `[datetime]` object
- assigns the `.CreationTime`, `.LastWriteTime`, & `.LastAccessTime` values to the datetime from the file name
- displays the changed values

here is the code ...

```
$Directory = $env:TEMP
$DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"

# create some test files
$TestFileList = @(
    'FileA_2017-10-15.pdf'
    'FileB_2016-04-08.pdf'
    'FileC_2018-01-30.pdf'
    'FileD_2019-09-09_1.pdf'
    'FileE_2015-05-05_2.pdf'
    )
foreach ($TFL_Item in $TestFileList)
    {
    $Null = New-Item -Path $Directory -Name $TFL_Item -ItemType File -Force
    }

$FileList = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $Directory -Filter '*.pdf' -File
foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList) {

    # removed split, added regex match to work with ever-growing list of variant file names
    $Null = $FL_Item.BaseName -match '_(?<DateString>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})'
    $DateString = $Matches.DateString
    $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat, $Null)

    $FL_Item.CreationTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastWriteTime = $date_from_file
    $FL_Item.LastAccessTime = $date_from_file

    # show the resulting datetime info
    '=' * 20
    $CurrentFileInfo = Get-Item -LiteralPath $FL_Item.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.FullName
    $CurrentFileInfo.CreationTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastWriteTime
    $CurrentFileInfo.LastAccessTime
    }
```

screen output ...

```
====================
C:\Temp\FileA_2017-10-15.pdf

2017 October 15, Sunday 12:00:00 AM
2017 October 15, Sunday 12:00:00 AM
2017 October 15, Sunday 12:00:00 AM
====================
C:\Temp\FileB_2016-04-08.pdf
2016 April 08, Friday 12:00:00 AM
2016 April 08, Friday 12:00:00 AM
2016 April 08, Friday 12:00:00 AM
====================
C:\Temp\FileC_2018-01-30.pdf
2018 January 30, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
2018 January 30, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
2018 January 30, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
====================
C:\Temp\FileD_2019-09-09_1.pdf
2019 September 09, Monday 12:00:00 AM
2019 September 09, Monday 12:00:00 AM
2019 September 09, Monday 12:00:00 AM
====================
C:\Temp\FileE_2015-05-05_2.pdf
2015 May 05, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
2015 May 05, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
2015 May 05, Tuesday 12:00:00 AM
```

i checked the files directly in explorer & they match the displayed values.

Comment: I followed your advice and encountered the below error:

Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."
At line:6 char:5
+     $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($File.BaseName.Split('_' ...
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FormatException
 
Exception setting "CreationTime": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime"."
At line:8 char:5
+     $file.CreationTime = $date_from_file

Comment: @JadonR - what is the exact name of the file? i tested with the ones you posted and those worked as expected.

Comment: @LotPings - should i replace the "replace this with that" with the full code?

Comment: That's what @Lee_Dailey advised and I just replaced that line from your code.

Comment: The exact name of the file I'm using is "FileA_2016-10-07.pdf". As long as that's the only file in the directory, the error I get is: Exception calling "ParseExact" with "3" argument(s): "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: @JadonR - that is VERY strange. it works for me ... so i am going to change my answer to include the full script so that you can test with that. [*grin*]

Comment: Thanks Lee. I think we are getting closer. I got the same output as you when I ran your full script. Testing further now...

Comment: I feel like a fool. I had a space between my basename and the underscore that was causing the problem. It is working. I just found some files that have an underscore at the end of the date as well. For example it could be ExampleFile_10-15-2017_2. Any way you can help me modify it to match BETWEEN two underscores? I would want it to match either way actually.

Comment: @JadonR - goofs ... they happen all the time. [*grin*] ///// for the various file names, please add one or two of each variant to you Original Post so folks can see what you have to work with.

Comment: I edited my original post to show some additional examples as they don't format correctly in the comments.

Comment: @JadonR - i modified my answer to include those variant names and a minor code change to handle them.

Comment: Working great. I have a handful of files that have two underscores before the date. So I made a second script from yours and changed the "Split('_')[1]" to a [2]. It errors for any that do not have two underscores but it works for those that do. It would be cool if I could merge them into a single script to handle both, but for now this is working.

Comment: @JadonR - as before, you need to provide a _full assortment of samples_ before anyone can program around them. i suspect that the regex method posted by LotPings is the better solution since it looks for _date strings_ while mine depends on splitting patterns.

Comment: all right ... i switched to a regex instead of a split - code updated, but not the input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. I was stuck without this thread. I ended up with a variation that matched any filename with a correctly formatted date, thus:

```
# Call like:
#   powershell -NoLogo -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Sta -NonInteractive -WindowStyle Normal -File ".\Rename_files_selected_folders_ModifyDateStamps.ps1" -Folder "T:\files" 
# 1. capture a commandline parameter 1 as a mandatory "Folder string" with a default value 
param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [string]$Folder = "T:\HDTV\autoTVS-mpg\Converted" ) 
[console]::BufferWidth = 512 
$DateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" 
write-output "Processing Folder: ",$Folder  
# 2. Iterate the files 
$FileList = Get-ChildItem -Recurse $Folder -Include '*.mp4','*.bprj','*.ts' -File 
foreach ($FL_Item in $FileList) { 
    $ixxx = $FL_Item.BaseName -match '(?<DateString>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})' 
    if($ixxx){ 
        #write-output $FL_Item.FullName 
        $DateString = $Matches.DateString 
        $date_from_file = [datetime]::ParseExact($DateString, $DateFormat, $Null) 
        $FL_Item.CreationTime = $date_from_file 
        $FL_Item.LastWriteTime = $date_from_file 
        $FL_Item | Select-Object FullName,CreationTime,LastWriteTime 
    } 
} 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211626/powershell-change-file-date-created-and-date-modified-based-on-filename
```